# Media keys only work when pressing Fn button

Tags: windows-8, media-keys

I'm using Windows 8 and have some problems with media keys.

They do work, but I need to press "FN" and then the key. When I got my computer it worked without pressing the FN button. Toshiba Satellite by the way, if that's important.

Any ideas?

Comment: install all packages & suites that came with your toshiba.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install Toshiba's Flash Card Support Utility.

Source: http://forums.computers.toshiba-europe.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=284057

(via Google: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=toshiba+satellite+fn+lock)